# Flutter connecting to PLC

Tags: android, flutter, tcp, plc

I have used a package in flutter to send TCP/IP to send data which is `flutter_socket_plugin` but the `PLC FX5U` isn't responding to the data that is being sent how can I set up the PLC to be a host or be able to communicate with the android flutter app and knowing the IP Address from the device.

I tried connecting the Flutter with the PLC FX5U through a router and it didn't work.

I have used SLMP, Melsoft, Unpassive, and Passive Methods and it doesn't seem to be working.

I can't find FX5U.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can achieve that is by **OPC UA** (passing by Web Services/REST Api). Here some info https://opcfoundation.org/about/opc-technologies/opc-ua/.
Otherwise you have to use property language/software/libraries/drivers of PLC producer (like Siemens or other) and at this point you must follow their guide lines by manuals of Brand/Model/year of production etc etc and in this case you have to use their mapping software to get/set PLC cells addresses/values as well.

Exists also generic PLC library .NET or Java and so one but there is the problem you have to know exactly cell mapping (like address and length) in order to avoid HW disasters. Actually I doesn't know a well-written flutter package to do that, so, means;

The easiest alternative remains: Using **OPC UA** server services then by that use its (REST Api/WebService)'s.